Issue with Inconsistent DID and VerKey Lengths Using DidSigner in Indy Plenum
I'm working on a project with Indy Plenum, and I encountered an issue with generating DIDs and verification keys. I'm using the following function to generate them from a 32-character seed:
import sys
import argparse
from plenum.common.signer_did import DidSigner

def generate_did_verkey(seed: str):
    """
    Generate DID and verification key using the provided seed.
    
    Args:
        seed (str): A 32-character long seed value.

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing the DID and verification key.
    """
    if len(seed) != 32:
        raise ValueError("The seed must be exactly 32 characters long.")
    
    seed_value = seed.encode()
    signer = DidSigner(seed=seed_value)
    did = signer.identifier
    verkey = signer.verkey

    return did, verkey

Even though I'm passing a seed that is exactly 32 characters long, the DidSigner class in Indy Plenum sometimes gives me a DID that is 22 characters long (which is expected and works), but other times it gives me a 21-character DID, which causes issues later when I try to use it with an Indy node function (throws an error due to invalid DID length).
Similarly, the verification key (verkey) is sometimes 23 characters (correct), but occasionally it gives me a 22-character verkey, which also causes problems down the line.
I’m not sure why the lengths of the DIDs and verkeys are inconsistent when the input seed is always 32 characters. I created a small script to call generate_did_verkey(seed) 10 times with random seeds, and here are the results:

Test Results:
root@indy-pool-4-nodes-node-1-79bf89ccd6-b7gt4:/indy_node/indy_network# python3 test_get_did_and_verkey.py 
Seed 1: 6Tzxx5GR3VOqurfEzYhPmhyYgvGgdsPx
DID: GzbU6UywWsndZhov6aLVD9 (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~2TxDRQRCPrXQHiNdSq77Mt (Length: 23)

Seed 2: Jp8WBrwxHXn5YCVL2pNKwKwrJuxoQIjI
DID: 7yMvyQ3tcCYVgsid5ky9Nq (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~QDUxbkNknGdFidzQtPG758 (Length: 23)

Seed 3: zAgaUG7vK7ZFI5J4g4yUkB0rxAXNcNSO
DID: TmGcz2c5fdSjwuhmxpuJRg (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~M8dRGxpfHPpfWPUrkchpui (Length: 23)

Seed 4: 4AG44VWxPNkufirKFJztcjzv4VlgHN6B
DID: 6f8mNreThwNJ7AJ5xsaY73 (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~7MkCDmm5hxcwNd2VnmiB7V (Length: 23)

Seed 5: h01iyHIGs7wGr1TANq5cMOMfv30pRk5C
DID: 7fNPiLQjpmnQjGJ9KyCJc7 (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~7ewe36QjzNMkFAsKVtficY (Length: 23)

Seed 6: ZG6DxtYzVqQDXuNMsUzNAL6cjnTQqwmO
DID: 3vBqosKemC4M16pwQd3BR6 (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~HJvaYU3BtWJxHucaCbG9gK (Length: 23)

Seed 7: ZafyqLLqhENdJMfBOaFsKuz8OFRKpNv1
DID: N8mXH8kXon5P5nJ5KVQK53 (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~2suZ4eyHmVJwQdPmLDvoZs (Length: 23)

Seed 8: ONCWCJvCHO6speTaJU3JkGjEP51PoisD
DID: JdhBRD8B8NqDTBqbArZZ2e (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~3J7Sp26EGGUXbKD2fCCftp (Length: 23)

Seed 9: IXQ1sHoi5w3hLdX4FRJYB3qYdPJ6Cqgw
DID: rbTbLZs69hX1zRJnzHu8Q (Length: 21)
VerKey: ~N2H55kCg8LcTEC4Jqh7dJA (Length: 23)

Seed 10: qjJkRI0iGmqkM6CTgmFwZcrRqTAoWKHQ
DID: FDmCMrGuMFphpafEQopZWz (Length: 22)
VerKey: ~7XuxKGQEDzookBv6wZksxR (Length: 23)

Has anyone experienced this issue with DidSigner in Indy Plenum before? Is there something wrong with how I'm generating the DIDs or using DidSigner?
